# Convert dynamic content to static in Numbers

Tags: mac, numbers

I have used some formulas in `Numbers` and I would like to change the dynamic values to static ones, so I can copy them to different sheets, without having any reference errors.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select and copy the source cells, then hit <kbd>⇧⌘V</kbd>, which is the default shortcut for the **Edit » Paste Formula Results** menu command.

(I assume that by *dynamic value,* you are referring to the **the result of the calculation of an entire formula** and not to the individual cell references you are using as part of the formula’s expression. Feel free to update and clarify your question if you disagree.)

[image: Screenshot of the menu command Edit » Paste Formula Results]

If you want the static results to persist in your original cells as well, just hit <kbd>⌘C</kbd> <kbd>⇧⌘V</kbd> to paste the results in place.

Comment: (+1) This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!